# How to give file copied by .NET File.Copy() method the correct permissions in Windows

Tags: .net, windows, permissions

I have a Windows permission problem that I need to solve. My .NET application uses an update mechanism where an extra update.exe is copied to %TEMP% and then executed. This update.exe then checks if it can write to the normal programm installation path - if not, it starts itself again with elevated rights. Then, the update process takes place: downloading files (including new version of the main application.exe) using the .NET File.Copy() method.
So far, everything is working.

But when trying to run the now updated application.exe, I cannot start it! The Windows security dialog says, that the "normal user" has no rights on that file whatsoever! I cannot even see the icon of the application. Changing the rights on that file to let normal users "read and execute" that file, it works again.

Here is my question:
is there any possibility to let Windows give the new copied file the correct user rights? Or do I have to do somethind special in .NET?

The application is installed in different customer environments where there is no other option then letting the main application run as a non-privileged user. The update (for which Windows UQC requires the admin password) is done by an administrator if needed.

Any help would be very appreciated.

-

Edit due to comment from Falco Alexander:

The folder has the following rights:
* CREATOR-OWNER: "special rights"
* SYSTEM: full control
* Administrators: full control
* User: read, execute and list folder contents
* Trusted Installer: list folder contents

Hope this additional infos help...

Comment: I guess there is sth. missing in the description?! Can you name the exact NTFS rights of the folder, because the newly copied file will inherit these

Comment: I added the information you asked...

Comment: this is quite strange and seems to be a side affect of the elevated updater. Please check the NTFS inheritance settings of the folder. bear in mind that .copy inherits the folder settings whereas.move does not. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved the issue by using `FileInfo.SetAccessControl()`.

That helped me and I hope that it will work on all customer installations as well.

Thanks to Falco Alexander, who pointed me to the access rights modifications.